# Handling very long log txt file with different line length with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, logging

I'm trying to import data to matlab from txt file which is length is about 1e6 lines.

the text is as follows :

```
[04 05 11 12] jiffies=100
[04 06 15 09] jiffies=3455
.
.
.
[00 02 07 07] jiffies=111200
```

I've managed to extract the first two numbers (which I need) without using a loop;

now I want to read only the number after the "jiffies=#" , If I am trying to use the same method

```
textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter', 'jiffies=')
```

but it's not working , any method without using loops ?

Answer (score 4):

You can skip values by using a star `*`. 
The complete formatting string for all data in your file is

```
'[%d %d %d %d] jiffies=%d'
```

To skip all the numbers in the front, simply put a star between `%` and `d`.

```
C = textscan(fid,'[%*d %*d %*d %*d] jiffies=%d');
```

which returns

```
C{1}

ans =

         100
        3455
      111200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import all of the data at once, you can open this file in the Import Tool:

```
uiimport(filename);
```

This will correctly remove the brackets and 'jiffies=' text, and can return you a numeric array of all the numbers.  You can also generate code from the Import Tool (click on the Import Selection dropdown/Generate script or function).  This may prove to handle any errors in the file better than using textscan directly.